# Rate Limit Exceeded Foursquare API

Tags: foursquare

I have a file contains 1000++ tweets which for each entry i want to get user's information from Foursquare API.
The problem is, i keep getting error Rate Limit Exceeded, is there a best practice to avoid Rate Limit Exceeded on Foursquare API?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You should limit your request rates. You can create a thread and then pause the api invocations for the specified interval. Or you can use RxJava. An example is mentioned below.

```
public static invokeRateLimitedFetch(List<RequestInfo> requests){
      //2 second pause             
      Observable.zip(Observable.from(requests),
               Observable.interval(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS), (obs,timer)->obs)
               .doOnNext(item -> {
                  //Invoke here use item
               }
).toList().toBlocking().first();

 }

}
```